# How to prevent arp spoofing?

Tags: network

I'm not sure I can handle doing it manually so is there a reliable program I can download that will automatically change the settings on my computer for me to prevent ARP spoofing. Will it matter if I am behind a router or will I have to change some router settings too.

Comment: You're using your computer as a hub?